# I want to move an ellipse slightly using the keyPressed() in Processing but when I do so it adds another ellipse instead of getting rid of one

Tags: java, animation, processing

Sorry if this is a silly question only started learning Java in processing and I am slightly confused. lol

[image: What happens when I press any key]
[image: What happens after I release any key]

```
boolean eyeMove = false;
boolean armMove = false;

void setup() {
  size(600, 800);
  smooth();
}

void draw() {

  stroke(1);
  fill(255);
  ellipse(300, 460, 230, 270);
  stroke(1);
  fill(188);
  ellipse(280, 220, 35, 95);
  ellipse(320, 220, 35, 95);
  fill(126);
  ellipse(280, 220, 20, 80);
  ellipse(320, 220, 20, 80);
  stroke(1);
  fill(255);
  ellipse(300, 300, 100, 100);
  fill(188);
  noStroke();
  ellipse(300, 460, 130, 170);
  fill(0);
  ellipse(240, 580, 40, 40);
  ellipse(360, 580, 40, 40);
  fill(0);
  ellipse(300, 320, 20, 10);
  fill(0);
  triangle(300, 330, 289, 344, 310, 344);
  fill(188);
  stroke(1);
  ellipse(280, 290, 20, 20);
  ellipse(320, 290, 20, 20);

  keyPressed();
}


void keyPressed() {
  if (!keyPressed) {
    fill(0);
    ellipse(390, 350, 40, 40);
    ellipse(210, 350, 40, 40);
  } else if (keyPressed) {
    armMove = true;
    fill(125);
    ellipse(390, 350, 40, 40);
    ellipse(230, 350, 40, 40);
  }
```

I have used mousePressed on the eyes of the rabbit and it works fine. I just am confused how this is causing problems now.

Comment: So you called "draw()" twice?  The problem might be that you aren't clearing the canvas before each call to draw(), but rather just drawing on top of what is already there?

Comment: Hey thanks for looking into this for me :) do you mean keyPressed? because in the code I posted it only has "draw()" once? I don't want to clear the whole canvas just the arm how does one do that? All the videos I have watched just show me how to clear the background, not one particular circle :/ or do you know of a good video to watch ?:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `draw() method isn't exactly just a drawing loop. It's the main loop of your program. As such, it doesn't clear the screen at every iteration of the loop, but just paints whatever you tell it to paint. In fact, you can paint in any method, as long as it's being called at some point.

The problem here is that you are re-painting the bunny *over the previous one*. You never "erase" your previous drawing. People usually uses the `background()` method to do so. I modified your sketch a little bit to show you what I mean:

```
void setup() {
  size(600, 800);
  smooth();
}

void draw() {
  background(128);
  
  stroke(1);
  fill(255);
  ellipse(300, 460, 230, 270);
  fill(188);
  ellipse(280, 220, 35, 95);
  ellipse(320, 220, 35, 95);
  fill(126);
  ellipse(280, 220, 20, 80);
  ellipse(320, 220, 20, 80);
  fill(255);
  ellipse(300, 300, 100, 100);
  fill(188);
  noStroke();
  ellipse(300, 460, 130, 170);  
  fill(0);
  ellipse(240, 580, 40, 40);
  ellipse(360, 580, 40, 40);
  ellipse(300, 320, 20, 10);
  triangle(300, 330, 289, 344, 310, 344);
  fill(188);
  stroke(1);
  ellipse(280, 290, 20, 20);
  ellipse(320, 290, 20, 20);

  if (keyPressed) {
    ellipse(390, 350, 40, 40);
    ellipse(230, 350, 40, 40);
  } else {
    ellipse(390, 350, 40, 40);
    ellipse(210, 350, 40, 40);    
  }
}
```

I'll be around if you have follow-up questions. Have fun!

Comment: Thank you so much this was very useful and makes sense :) :). If I was to use the void keyPressed function or void mousePressed function would you have to use the background in each or only in the draw() ?

Comment: @webDesigner if the answer was useful vote it up and it answered your question please also give it the green check mark (so other users in the future know this is the solution).

Comment: I ask this because when I do this                                                                            
  void keyPressed() {
  if (keyPressed) { 
    ellipse(390, 350, 40, 40);
    ellipse(230, 350, 40, 40);
  } 
}                                                                                                                                         it starts to glitch and doesn't work ?

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza did it there :)

Comment: Excellent! :) Much appreciated

Comment: I removed the `keyPressed()` line from your `draw()` method, it may be the point where our work is different. I suggest that you copy and paste my code snippet in a new sketch and play around with it to get the hang of it.

Comment: The `keyPressed()` method acts as an event (I haven't read how it works under the hood, but it seems to be quite similar). This means that it'll be called at any time it's trigger condition happens. If you updated the `draw` loop with the `if (keyPressed)` condition as showed in my code but left the `keyPressed()` method elsewhere in your code, both will apply. You probably don,t want that. Comment the method and see if it helps.

Comment: To answer your question about using the `background()` method, I would use it only in the `draw()` method. Every time you call the `background()` method, it paints over *everything*. It would be like erasing everything you already have already drawn and just drawing what's left until the end of the loop.

Comment: Thank you so much @laancelot. You have honestly been such a great help to me in understanding this :) I was getting so frustrated and sometimes when I try to use google I end up getting the most random results  

Comment: @webDesigner My pleasure, your question was well-written, with working example and relevant pictures. Next time, maybe use your first words to pinpoint your problem instead of making excuses, as future users having similar problems will see these words in their search. Welcome to SO !!